# If string is in another list, call on the next value in said list (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

Let's say I have a value *callfunc* in list *list1* that I want to call on the next value in the list, but only if *callfunc* is in *list2* (it is). I have this code:

```
for instr in list1:
if instr in list2:
    eval(instr(list1[list1.index(instr)+1]))
```

And I get this error message:

```
eval(instr(list1[list1.index(instr)+1]))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm trying to get the output as a function, not a string of:

```
callfunc(75)
```

That will, in the script, call *callfunc* on *75*.

lists 1 and 2:

```
list1 = [callfunc, 75]
list2 = [callfunc]
```

I have no idea where to go from here. Help would be greatly appreciated.

*callfunc* is a **string**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
eval(instr+"("+list1[list1.index(instr)+1]+")")
```

This will create the call string you wanted.

Then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) question and it's answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you use `eval` here. If you want to call the function, just do this:

```
for ifunc in list1:
if ifunc in list2:
    d = ifunc(list1[list1.index(ifunc)+1])
    print(d)
```

Comment: Returning:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. 

I'm a noob at this and I really don't know why it's returning this.

Comment: Is `callfunc` really a function?

Comment: ...it's always the simplest things, isn't it? No, it's a string.

Comment: It a string? In both the list?

Comment: Why bother? I mean, you could totally put a function in the list, and it should work with my code above.